# openatrium installation error?

Tags: database, installation, distributions

I installed openatrium locally on Wampserver2.4, after installing all the 186 modules, I goes to site home page, but it show following error[image: error]

how to cope this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to do a change in my.ini file which is configuration file for your mysql server.

Change

1. open the my.ini file.
2. you might not have this (max_allowed_packet) line already there.
3. So you need to add this line at some point in this file.

   max_allowed_packet=24M
4. Save the file
5. Restart mysql server.

Reference:
https://drupal.org/node/163145

Comment: arpitr my.ini file at C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\ have two max_allowed_packet one at 
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M other at                            # The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M which one i replace .whole my.ini file host at http://freetexthost.com/shgem0r1dk